# What episode of fairy tail are these screenshots from?

Tags: fairy-tail

I found these in an amv online and I wanted to know what episode(s) they're from. It looks like Natsu is losing control of his fire or something related to that.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is from a special OVA from the very first season of Fairy Tail, I believe it is *Welcome to Fairy Hills*. It was after Wendy just joined. The scenes are from when Natsu accidentally saw the old man swimming naked, and is spitting fire everywhere along with Gajil and Grey who also did the same thing and ended up destroying the basement.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the OVA of Fairy Tail Episode one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STgQUNJryOQ